# Join a rectangle annotation with another annotation in JFreeChart?

Tags: jfreechart

I have used `XYAnnotation` and drawn a rectangle in `xylinechart`. Now how can I join it with another rectangle annonation?

Comment: Join how? Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows what you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use an `XYLineAnnotation`

```java
plot.addAnnotation(new XYBoxAnnotation( 0.5,0.5,1.5,1.5));
plot.addAnnotation(new XYBoxAnnotation( 4.5,3.5,5.5,4.5));
plot.addAnnotation(new XYLineAnnotation( 1.5,1.5,4.5,3.5));
```

[image: Connected XYBoxAnnotation]

Comment: Thank you Graham for your reply.I was trying for a union of two rectangles when they intersect each other.But then I will have to use a XYPolygonAnnotation.

Comment: @ranu To do that I think you would have to implement `XYAnnotation`